# Google apps script running in the background and depleting my quota?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On my paid Google account, I have a lot of sheets using various scripts to fetch urls. I know there is a daily quote of fetches set, but the issue I have is that even if I don't open any of my sheets with scripts for over 24 hours, and then I open one, I get the over quota error message: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. I wouldn't have thought scripts would be running in the background, ie. without me opening them, but I can't explain this in any other way - does anyone know if this is so? Another way to put the question, how can I avoid getting such error?

Comment: [The quotas for URL Fetch Calls](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) are pretty high, we'd need to see some of your scripts and triggers to be able to figure out what's eating your quota every day. Do you have any crazy triggers that run every minute for example?

Comment: Hi Ross - I don't have any triggers setup (none are listed on my script.google.com page under Triggers). Wouldn't that mean necessarily that any script would be run only when the container sheet is open? cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any time based triggers set up for other scripts?

You can check by going to [script.google.com](https://script.google.com) and selecting My Triggers on the left hand side.  Some of you scripts may be set to run even if you are not present.

Comment: Hi Brett - I have no triggers, the page is empty.

Comment: Could you share a script that is causing the issue?

Comment: I am using 2 kinds of scripts on many sheets: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON and https://github.com/tomayac/wikipedia-tools-for-google-spreadsheets